# How to jump to next id in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a course_content table and lesson table like below

```
course_id  lesson_id content_id seq_no
    1         1          1        1
    1         1          2        2
    1         5          3        1
    1         5          4        2
    1         8          12       1  


leson_id lesson_no course_id

   1        1          1
   5        3          1
   8        2          1
```

I want to have a next previous button in my app. when next is clicked if if current lesson has next content query should give next content id and if it does not have next content it should jump to next lesson and first content. sequence number for content is seq_no and lesson is lesson_no

I have made below query but i'm unable to jump to next lesson

FOR NEXT CLICK:

```
SELECT * 
FROM course_content
WHERE course_id =1
AND content_id = ( 
SELECT MIN( content_id ) 
FROM course_content
WHERE lesson_id =1
AND content_id >21
ORDER BY seq_no ASC )
```

FOR PREVIOUS CLICK

```
SELECT * 
FROM course_content
WHERE course_id =1
AND content_id = ( 
SELECT MAX( content_id ) 
FROM course_content
WHERE lesson_id =1
AND content_id <2
ORDER BY seq_no DESC )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT c.course_id
     , c.lesson_id
     , c.content_id
     , c.seq_no
     , l.lesson_no
  FROM course_content c
  JOIN lesson l 
    ON l.lesson_id = c.lesson_id
 WHERE c.course_id = 1
   AND l.lesson_no     >= :curr_lesson_no
   AND (   c.seq_no     > :curr_seq_no
       OR
           l.lesson_no  > :curr_lesson_no2 
       )
 ORDER
    BY l.lesson_no
       , c.seq_no
   LIMIT 1
```

just supply the values `lesson_no` and `seq_no` of the current row into the query parameters

---

if we can't preserve the `lesson_no` and `seq_no` of the current row, and all we have is `content_id`, then we can run a query to get those

```
 SELECT cl.lesson_no   AS curr_lesson_no
      , cc.seq_no      AS curr_seq_no
   FROM course_content cc
   JOIN lesson cl 
     ON cl.lesson_id = cc.lesson_id
  WHERE cc.content_id  = :curr_content_id
  ORDER
     BY cl.lesson_no
      , cc.seq_no
  LIMIT 1
```

---

We could roll those two queries together ...

```
SELECT c.course_id
     , c.lesson_id
     , c.content_id
     , c.seq_no
     , l.lesson_no
  FROM ( SELECT cl.lesson_no   AS curr_lesson_no
              , cc.seq_no      AS curr_seq_no
           FROM course_content cc
           JOIN lesson cl 
             ON cl.lesson_id = cc.lesson_id
          WHERE cc.content_id  = :curr_content_id
          ORDER
             BY cl.lesson_no
              , cc.seq_no
          LIMIT 1
       ) q
  JOIN lesson l
    ON l.lesson_no   >= q.curr_lesson_no
  JOIN course_content c
    ON c.lesson_id = l.lesson_id
 WHERE c.course_id = 1
   AND (   c.seq_no     > q.curr_seq_no
       OR
           l.lesson_no  > q.curr_lesson_no 
       )
 ORDER
    BY l.lesson_no
       , c.seq_no
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what are curr_lesson_no,curr_seq_no,curr_lesson_no2,curr_seq_no2. why i should pass two lesson and two seq nos

Comment: when i provide the last content id of current lesson, it should jump to next lesson and give that lesson id and first content id of that lesson. seq_no is for content sequencing and lesson_no is for lesson sequencing @spencer7593

Comment: i dont want to pass lesson no and seq no instead i will pass current lesson id and content id. automatically next content id based on seq_no and if end of content id then next lesson id based on lesson no should come

Comment: @Lavanya: then you will need to do a lookup of the `seq_no` and `lesson_no` of the current row, based on the value you do have , `content_id`.  And then those values of `seq_no` and `lesson_no` can be passed into the query to get the next record. We can roll the query for `seq_no` and `lesson_no` into an inline view, so it can be together in one query,